# How to make the "Open in editor" functionality to work in VueDevtools

Tags: vue.js, vue-devtools

I would like to use the "Open in editor" functionality in VueDevtools but I always got an error in my terminal saying:

```
Could not open MakeUpStudio.vue in the editor.
The editor process exited with an error: (code 1).

To specify an editor, specify the EDITOR env variable or add "editor" field to your Vue project config.
```

So I followed [this documentation](https://github.com/emanuelmutschlechner/vuejs-vue-devtools/blob/master/docs/open-in-editor.md) but it doesn't change anything. What can I do?

Comment: What did you tried so far? What is your configuration?

Comment: I tried to set the EDITOR env variable to `code` as I use VSCode, and the following config: https://github.com/emanuelmutschlechner/vuejs-vue-devtools/blob/master/docs/open-in-editor.md#webpack

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution following this [GitHub comment](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/821#issuecomment-851621967). As I use Vue.js v2, I need to use the `setup` hook instead of the `before` one.